# Circuit analysis- boost controller IC frequency change

Tags: bjt, dc-dc-converter, boost

[image] can anyone explain how this circuit works. A little background, this is a circuit which is used to change the switching frequency  of a boost controller IC , so that it doesn't operate at a single frequency and the operation is over a range of frequencies. V2 can be thought of as a pulse coming from the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circuits don't fall from the sky so next time please indicate where you found this circuit.

Q2 and Q3 with their surrounding components make an Astable Multivibrator. Go  [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html) for an explanation on how such a circuit works.

Instead of resistors R2 and R3 being connected to Vcc as in a "normal" Astable Multivibrator, here they are connected to the emitter of Q1. Q1 just buffers (copies with a 0.7 V drop) the voltage across C1. The voltage across C1 is the voltage from the control input with some filtering.

That filtered and buffered control voltage is then used as the supply voltage of part of the Astable Multivibrator and that will influence the oscillation frequency as the voltage Vmid determines how fast the capacitors in the Astable Multivibrator can charge.

Comment: Could you please explain how the voltage at Vmid determines how fast the capacitors can charge? Vmid wave form will be a capacitor charging and discharging waveform,right ?

Comment: Have you read the explanation from the link I included? For your circuit: when Q2 is on, C3 charges through R2. How much charge current flows depends on Vmid. Higher Vmid => more voltage across R2 => faster charging.

Comment: One more thing, could you please tell me why the emitter follower is used at the control input after the RC network ?

Comment: The emitter follower **buffers** the voltage from C1. Without Q1 the current into R2 and R3 would need to be delivered through R5 and R6, that would lower the voltage too much and disturb the filtering by R5, R6 and C1. The emitter follower is there so that the current into R2 and R3 can be delivered without distrurbing the filtering.

Comment: Thank you so much , it is very clear now. Could you tell me which transistor switches on first , according to me transistor Q3 would switch on first , since 18k is lower than 20k , is my understanding right ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't really matter if Q2 or Q3 is first as the oscillator will just start to run and once it oscillates it doesn't matter how it started. You could make R2 and R3 the same value and then it will be random if Q2 or Q3 starts first (assuming all components are exactly identical).

Comment: I wanted to know which turns on first because I was trying to understand the charging and discharging paths of the capacitors.

Comment: But if R2 and R3 both had the same value, whichever transistor turns on first is left to chance, it is random. In such cases, just pick a transistor (it does not matter which one) and assume it is conducting, this means the other isn't conduction (that's how this circuit behaves). Then given one transistor is on and the other is off, analyze what happens, how the capacitors charge and what that will cause. There is no need to know which transistor is "first", just pick one and reason from there.

Comment: Thank you, R6 and C1 form the RC circuit , but I couldn't understand the use of resistance R5. But when I simulate the circuit without R6 , I'm getting a steep triangle wave at the capacitor . Could you please tell me the role of resistor R6 in the above circuit . It would be a great help, thank you .

Comment: could you have a look at my calculation for selection of the component values for Rb, Rc and C , so that I get 700khz frequency of oscillation.