# RC circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I don't understand the use of R5 in the circuit above , could anyone explain.There is already another thread regarding this , but my doubt wasn't answered there , so thought I'll create another thread, sorry about this. Help me in the comments , and I'll take it down. [image]

Comment: Telling where you found it or what the application is could help to get a better answer. Or point to the other thread

Comment: This is the other thread. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356952/circuit-analysis-boost-controller-ic-frequency-change/356959?noredirect=1#comment859417_356959

Answer (score 1):

It is the bias voltage for Q1, which needs to be ON by a small amount so the multivibrator (oscillator) will continue to work, else it would stop with no bias and no modulation signal.

Under normal conditions Q2 and Q3 form an oscillator. Notice R2 and R3 are not the same value. This slight imbalance insures the circuit will oscillate.

V2 and Q1 form a modulator so that the oscillator changes frequency by the rate V2 changes. With current values the oscillator works in the 40 KHZ range.

Comment: Could you please explain  how you calculated the oscillation frequency to be 80Khz?

Comment: My mistake-it should be 40 KHZ. But it is dependent on V2. I used 1/2*pi*R*C*2 as a nominal frequency. It will produce a square wave of less than 50% duty cycle.(C2/C3/R2/R3)

Comment: But I just am not able to understand the use of R5, because when I simulate without it , the circuit still works but a disturbance is observed on the discharging waveform and hence the oscillation pulse is also distorted at the lower frequency end .

Comment: Without R5 the circuit would have no bias voltage and would not oscillate.

Answer (score 0):

It's the bias for transistor Q1. It nominally pulls the base up to the supply rail, and then your pulse is connected to it via the 10k series resistance.